# Reactjs props.match.params.id do not work in react-router-dom 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Goal:
After updatering react-router-dom from version 4 to 6 you should be enable to use this.props.match.params.id in the class PostItem

Problem:
After updatering the react-router-dom  to 6 you are not enable to use this.props.match.params.id in the class PostItem in order to display value 11.

What part of the code needs to be changed in order to display the value of the parameter in the class PostItem?

Stackblitz:
Before
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-routing-6-reading-url-params-8my95l?

After
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-routing-6-reading-url-params-ezzuzf?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? `element` is not `component`, so why would you expect them to behave the same? Also please include relevant code in the question. Stackblitz links are fine for *supporting* info, but the question needs to be self-sufficient *on-site*.

Comment: With `element`, it is very clear what props are being passed to `PostItem` -- none (`<PostItem />`). With `component`, react router is injecting route props, which is why you only pass a reference.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element